# Why can't I set my indexed variable equal to an integer in my if statement?

Tags: python, probability

I'm writing a simulation of streaks in basketball, how likely it is players have streaks of 5 baskets in a row, assuming the likelihood of making a shot is 50/50. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def bas(T):
    basket = np.zeros((T))
    streaks = 0
    for t in range(0,T):
        chance = random.random()
        if chance > 0.5:
            basket[t] = basket[t-1] + 1
        else:
            basket[t] = 0
    for t in range(0,T):
        if basket[t] = 5:
            streaks += 1
 return streaks
```

I get an error for the second if statement if I set basket[t] = 5 but not if it is >=,<=
The variable streaks, written in the current way, will return a higher (and consequently incorrect) value if I use >= rather than =. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you mean == rather than =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

= is assignment. you want comparison, which is ==

Answer (score 1):

your else statement has a typo:  you are setting basket[t] with this line:

```
if basket[t] = 5
```

when you want to be checking it with two equals:

```
if basket[t] == 5
```